# Loop through text file and add to MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, file, loops

I have a local text file which has a format of:

```
256328,899087
721299,109901
310101,001735
```

The first number in each line represents an index number under the "position" sub document, while the second number represents an index number for the user (not in the position sub document - see below)

```
     var User = new Schema({
        _id: ObjectId,
        name: String,
        index_number:Number,
        matching:Number,
    position: [{ 
        title: String,
        index_number: Number,
        matching:Number,
}],
```

What I need to do is loop through the text file, and for each of the first numbers on the line, find the position subdocument which matches this number, then take the second number and insert it into the "matching" field.

What I have so far:

```
  fs.readFile("result.txt", 'utf8', function(err, data) {

        var arrLines = data.split("\n");
        console.log(arrLines[0]); // which will return 256328,899087 but I need 

var index_number = arrLines.map(function(element) { return element.index_number })
    User.update({"position.$.index_number" : { "$in" : index_number }}{
    "push":{
      // I'm stuck here
    }
  }
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but you are supposed to put some effort in it, and ask a question about exact problem. "reading the text file seems complicated" is not quite a coding one.

Comment: First parse your text file (for me it looks like a csv)  into a array. Then run a MongoDB find query using an 'in' operator for position array for every item and update return document

Comment: Sorry @AlexBlex , I've been working on it and ive updated the question with what I have, didn't mean to leave it so empty! Any help is appreciated

Comment: @PPB ive updated my question but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong, if you have any idea I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: First of all, please confirm your `index_number` is not empty. I don't see how `{ return element.index_number }` can return anything. Then, please read http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.bulkWrite. Your map function should return an array of updates for each document. And please, stop duplicate the question.